# Is spectral density conserved after aliasing?

Tags: power-spectral-density, downsampling, aliasing

Will the integral of the PSD of a down-sampled signal still equal the variance in all cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The aliased component will interfere with the non-aliased components and the interference can constructive or destructive.

Trivial example:

$$x[n] = \sin\left(\frac\pi2n\right)$$

If you down sample this to $y[n] = x[2n]$, you get all zeros.